# What do YOU use for your Windows Server backup solution?

Tags: windows, backup

I know there are many choices, from builtin ntbackup, to FOSS, to commercial to custom script, but I was wondering  what YOUR choice is for your servers and environment and a brief explanation of why.

As each environment and requirements differ, there is no one right solution, except that you should be backing up and verifying restoration regularly.

As a bonus, do you use D2D2D? D2D2T? D2D2Cloud?

Answer (score 1):

We do system backups via wbadmin or NT Backup to a NAS share which then gets backed up to an "enterprise" backup solution. We have found that the restore procedures for third party backup products (at least the ones we have used) are cumbersome and prone to failure.

Answer (score 0):

We use a mix of D2D and straight D2T, though everything ends up on tape at least once a month. Our software is Veritas/Symantec Netbackup, mostly because it interfaces quite nicely with our Quantum i40 tape library and has plugins for everything under the sun. Solaris, Windows, NDMP, Exchange, SQL, and even VMWare are no problem.